# Dymos + OpenMDAO 3.17 creating dozens of reports, can't turn them off

Tags: openmdao

Hi all I just upgraded to OpenMDAO 3.17, and I have Dymos 3.14 installed as well.

When I run my problem dozens N^2 reports, under the reports folder, are created. Each consists of an N^2 report in a folder called "problemN" where N is 1-60. In fact most of the N^2 report only shows the trajectory / dymos part of the overall problem.

I called os.environ['OPENMDAO_REPORTS'] = 'none' at the top of my script but that doesn't seem to do anything.

What's the right way to run off reports? I did look at this page

https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/model_visualization/reports_system.html#controlling-which-reports-get-run

and set the Environmental variable, I think

Comment: This should be resolved now 
 https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/pull/741

Comment: updated to dev version and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That fix should do it, alternatively you could try setting

`os.environ['OPENMDAO_REPORTS'] = 0`

in case it's string part of this that's causing an issue. We definitely have devs who disable this by default when debugging, so if nothing else setting the environment variable outside of python should do the trick.

In any case, I just put up an issue to disable these by default for the subproblems generated by simulate. We should be able to have this on the master branch either tomorrow or Monday.