# How do I turn off report generation in OpenMDAO 3.17?

Tags: openmdao

How can I turn of the report generation in OpenMDAO 3.17?
I've tried add the following code to the top of my script:

```
import os
os.environ['OPENMDAO_REPORTS'] = 'none'
```

In place of `'none'`, I've also tried `'0'`, `'false'`, and `'off'` as mentioned [here](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.17.0/features/model_visualization/reports_system.html) in the OpenMDAO documentation. This is the only way I've seen to change the environment variables.
Are there other ways to permanently change them such as through the command prompt? I'm relatively new to python, so spelling it out for me would be helpful.

Also, I know this is a [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71961742/dymos-openmdao-3-17-creating-dozens-of-reports-cant-turn-them-off), but I don't have enough points to add a comment to that post. So I've had to create a new post. That post also mentioned a PR, but the summary indicates the report generation was only fixed for some Dymos functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the setting via a python script (as your question shows) you are only changing it for that active python session. Not permenantly.

You don't say whether you're on windows or linux, which changes the specific method you would use to achieve your goal; Generally though, you can set the environment variable so that its given whenever you open a terminal. This will have the effect you desire.

On windows, you set environment variables [via a small system GUI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html). On linux you change them by [adding a line to a config file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables#:%7E:text=To%20set%20an%20environment%20variable%20everytime%2C%20use%20the%20export%20command,script%20it%20will%20not%20work.) (usually `.bashrc`). On Mac the file name is sometimes `.bash_profile` or `.profile`.

Comment: Another easy way to set environment variables, at least on linux or mac os, is to just add the environment var setting at the start of the command line.  For example, if you normally run `python myscript.py`, you can turn off the reports by running `OPENMDAO_REPORTS=0 python myscript.py`.  Note that this method only updates the environment variable for that particular run and doesn't modify the environment for the current shell.

Comment: Thanks. I am using windows. Sorry about that. I added the variable and restarted my IDE and that did the trick! My batch optimizations run much faster now that it isn't making the reports after each one.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get them to switch off via environmental variables, whether setting them in the python script or from the terminal, but when creating the problem this worked

```
p = om.Problem(model=om.Group(), reports=False)
```